# Insert variable in regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following code:

```
word = "three"
test_1 = /\bthree\b/i.match( "one two three four" ) 
test_2 = /\#{word}\b/i.match( "one two three four" ) 

render json: {
              test_1: !!test_1, // => true
              test_2: !!test_2  // => false
             }.to_json
```

Why is test_2 false when test_1 is true? Can someone tell me how to properly insert a variable into my regular expression?

Comment: You left the first b out of test_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you escaped your `#` character.

try:

```
test_2 = /\b#{word}\b/i.match( "one two three four" )
```

Comment: Oh. thanx for that.